Is there a mitzvah of Kavod Yom Kippur
According to Halacha, is there a mitzvah of Kavod Yom Kippur or no? On the one hand, it is a day of affliction, so the usual mitzvah of Oneg with regards to nice food etc. is not there, but is there still an obligation to honor the holiday with nice clothing because it is called a Shabbat Shabbaton?

In Shabbat 119a it says, אֲמַר לֵיהּ רֵישׁ גָּלוּתָא לְרַב הַמְנוּנָא: מַאי דִּכְתִיב ״וְלִקְדוֹשׁ ה׳ מְכוּבָּד״? אֲמַר לֵיהּ: זֶה יוֹם הַכִּפּוּרִים, שֶׁאֵין בּוֹ לֹא אֲכִילָה וְלֹא שְׁתִיָּה, אָמְרָה תּוֹרָה: כַּבְּדֵהוּ בִּכְסוּת נְקִיָּה. The Exilarch said to Rav Hamnuna: What is the meaning of that which is written, “The holy one of God is honored” (Isaiah 58:13)? Rav Hamnuna said to him: That is Yom Kippur, when there is no eating or drinking, and so the Torah said: Honor it with a clean garment. Rashi there says since it says וקראת לשבת עונג it implies that לקדוש ה is not going on the Shabbat part but on Yom kippur, that you need to give Yom Kippur some kavod. The Maharsha writes וְקָרָאתָ לַשַּׁבָּת עֹנֶג implies delight in eating, and ולִקְדוֹשׁ ה' implies entirely for the sake of Hashem without eating. We say like this in Perek Eilu Devarim that everyone agrees that we need לָכֶם, and it also says לה, if so  ולִקְדוֹשׁ ה' is not talking about Shabbat, rather it's referring to Yom Kipur which is also called a “Shabbat.” The Rif (Yoma 2b), Rosh (Yoma 8:9), Meiri (Shabbat 119a), Orchot Chaim (Hilchot Yom Kippur 27), and Manhig (Hilchot Fast of Yom Kippur 27), all bring this halacha of kavod Yom Kippur which is achieved by wearing clean and nice clothing, etc.
The Mordechai (Yoma 725) and Rema 610:4 bring the practice of setting a nice tablecloth on the table for Yom Kippur.
The Mamar Mordechai 610:3 and the Sdei Chemed (אס"ד מע' יום הכיפורים א, יז) talk about bringing kavod to Yom Kippur by putting sefarim on the table to learn Torah which is the ultimate kavod. The Ben Ish Chai (מקבציאל א, וילך מא) says to specifically put Chamisha Chumshei Torah on the table.
In the Aruch Hashulchan 610:2 he writes to make the beds and clean the house for Yom Kippur.
Link used: https://ph.yhb.org.il/plus/15-07-01/
